# Input parameter type error when calling Java function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

If I have a function defined in Java like this:

```
private void runInference(float[][][][] input, float[][][][] output){
  //body
}
```

When I call it in kotlin, the input parameter type of the interface became :

```
Array<Array<Array<FloatArray!>!>!>
```

I have checked Kotlin documents and I found that the Float member of FloatArray was NonNull. But I need the member of the four-dimensional array to be nullable as input parameter like

```
Array<Array<Array<Array<Float?>>>>.
```

Is there any way to do so? Please give me some advice or idea. Thanks!

Comment: `float` in java is primitive and never nullable. Use `Float` class if you want it to be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the fields nullable then you will have to fo something like this `Array<Array<Array<FloatArray?>?>?>`. This will accept null values too.